# Problem with CRUD(update) Upload File "call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null"

Tags: php, laravel

I want to Update an image using Laravel storage file system in my admin data. However, there's an error when I attempt to upload an image

Iam using Laravel 5.7

Here is my create, the create is success

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //
        $product = new \App\Product;
        $product->product_name = $request->get('product_name');
        $product->desc = $request->get('desc');
        $product->stock = $request->get('stock');
        $product->price = $request->get('price');
        $product->category = $request->get('category');



        $img = $request->file('img');

        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $img->move(public_path('img'), $new_name);
        $product->img = $new_name;
        $product->save();

        return redirect('admin')->with('success', 'Data Produk telah ditambahkan'); 
    }
```

Here is my update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $product = $request->all();
        $product= \App\Product::find($id);
        $new_name = $request->file('img')->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = 'img/';
        $proses = $request->file('img')->move($destinationPath, $new_name);

        if($request->hasFile('img'))
        {
            $product = array(
                    'product_name' => $product['product_name'],
                    'desc'=> $product['desc'],
                    'stock'=> $product['stock'],
                    'price'=> $product['price'],
                    'category'=> $product['category'],
                    'img' => $new_name,
                );

            $product->save() ;
            return redirect('admin')->with('success', 'Data Produk telah ditambahkan'); 
        }


    }
```

Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Comment: probably you are not sending an image file on update. check that out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no image file attach while updating. You can use my code as reference.
Don't forget to check for the input field in your update field.
First check if there is image file or not. Then, go for getting name, extension and other staff.

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $product= \App\Product::find($id);

    if (empty($product)) {
        Flash::error('product not found');

        return redirect(route('products.index'));
    }
    if ($request->hasFile('product_img')) {
        $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('product_img')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('product_img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $new_product_img = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $request->file('product_img')->move('images/products', $new_product_img);
        Storage::delete('products/'.$product->product_img);
        $input['product_img']= $new_product_img;
    }
    $product= $this->productRepository->update($input, $id);

    Flash::success('product updated successfully.');

    return redirect(route('products.index'));
}
```

Comment: mention not we are here to help each other